# A question about L-Citrulline

Tags: biochemistry, blood-circulation, amino-acids, mitochondria, liver

I know that L-Citrulline enters in the second step of urea cycle in the liver mitochondria and I wonder if a person takes an overdose of L-Citrulline wouldn't that cause mild hyperammonemia or at least cause an increase in the glutamine amino acid?